# Some of the members of BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs are "COM object" instead of the documented types

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to use Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher in a Windows desktop application.  When a BLE advertisement is received, I get a Received event with a BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs object as one of the arguments.

One of the things I need from those event arguments is the list of service UUIDs, which both the documentation and the Object Browser show as being of type IList:

```
public IList<Guid> ServiceUuids { get; }
```

When my event handler actually executes, though, that member (and several others) show up as type System._ComObject instead of the documented type.

[Screenshot of member types at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ygW0.png)

I assume that this is something more generic about using classes from that namespace in a non-UWP app?  How do I get access to those members with their documented types?

Comment: The debugger is telling you something you probably did not want to know.  Yes, all UWP objects are actually COM interfaces under the hood.  Pretty invisible, usually, thanks to the *language projection*, it makes them look like .NET types.  These specific properties are projected as `IList<T>`.  But are actually collection types written in a native language, C++ in this case. I *think* the debugger can still handle normal .NET expressions for them, like ManufacturerData[0].

Comment: It's not so much the debugger I'm concerned about as what's happening when the code is running, but the behavior is the same.  When I try to use the ServiceUuids member, I get an exception that the cast is invalid.

You're right, though, that some members come across the way I need them.  Is there anything I can do about the members that don't?